# Blazor 8 Server CustomAuthenticationStateProvider error

Tags: blazor-server-side

I got an error in Blazor server custom auth, and the error massge I received as the below while I start up the app.

InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required 'IAuthenticationService' service. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthentication' in the application startup code.

My code in program.cs as following.

Did I missing somwthing the the program.cs ?

Thanks very much.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.


builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ProtectedSessionStorage>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    x => new UnitOfWork(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BbChkContext>().UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbConnString"))));

builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();

//builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState(); 

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/PageNotFound");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();
```